# Slow Safari rendering giving inconsistent dimensions of just-appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm working on some code I inherited that uses jQuery to generate some DIV blocks containing text and images.  It generates the blocks, appends them to the page, then calls outerHeight() on the blocks' inner text elements and uses those heights to calculate how big the accompanying images should be.

In all browsers except Safari, things work fine.

In Safari, when outerHeight() is called, sometimes the just-appended elements aren't fully rendered, so the measurement returned is not accurate, and the resulting page doesn't look right.  I can see this in the debugger - my breakpoint is hit just after an incorrect outerHeight() is saved, after a second or two I see the rendering catch up, and calling outerHeight() again gives the correct value.

I've tried to serialize this sequence more explicitly using setTimeout and to call outerHeight() a bit later in the code.  This made the issue happen less frequently, but it still happens sometimes.

I feel like this has to be a common pattern - get the dimensions of just-appended elements.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimenting with various delays, I saw that most of the time, Safari would finish rendering the appended elements after no more than 250ms or so.  To deal with this issue, I use setTimeout to run a function after a delay to check whether the previously measured heights match the current ones in the DOM.  If they don't, then I know that the rendering has changed, and I re-do the layout of these elements.